# GWT - JSNI - passing JavaScriptObject to Java function

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

I have an JSNI method which adds a message listener to the window.

```
/*-{
    var that = this;
    $wnd.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
        var params = event.message.params; 
    });
*/
```

Here, `params` is an object with key-value pairs.

I also have a class, let's call it `MyClass` from `com.mypackage`.

What I would like to do now is to call a method `receiveMessage` of `MyClass` from inside the JSNI, passing `params` as a `JavaScriptObject` object (which I assume would be best, but I'm open to suggestions - stringified JSON maybe?). However I don't know what to put as param-signature type.

```
that.@com.mypackage.MyClass::receiveMessage( ??? )(params);
```

Another thing is that I'm not sure how I would handle this `JavaScriptObject` inside `receiveMessage()` to get the key-value pairs in Java.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to pass `params` to `receiveMessage()` and read it as a key value pairs?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe:  `that.@com.mypackage.MyClass::receiveMessage(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(params);`

Comment: @sergey-bezvershenko you should put that as an answer (also, if there's no overload, one can use `(*)` as the parameters list)

Comment: Or even better, just use `DomGlobal.window.addEventListener` from elemental2, and write it all in Java. But if you do go this route (I assume to support an old version of GWT), don't forget about `$entry` wrapping the function.

Comment: @ColinAlworth how do you wrap a function with `$entry` in Java?

Comment: You don't - that is, it is possible, but jsinterop is going to try to move us away from this as a habit. Exception handling is already fixed in gwt 2.8.2, we just need to work out some new habits around schedule finally/deferred.

Comment: @ColinAlworth maybe this warrants a question on it's own? I couldn't find much info on how to implement these boundary scenarios properly with JsInterop. Or did I just miss some documentation?

Comment: A new question here or on the gwt mailing list would be appropriate - it has been discussed, but not in great depth, and we don't have new docs that reflect the changes required yet.